# didSelectRowAtIndexPath checking rows and sections in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a UiTableView that populates data in different sections.

```
struct ResultRow {
   var name: String
   var dateRanges: [[NSDate]]
   var hours: [Int]
}

var result : [ResultRow] = []
var selectedMarks2 : [ResultRow] = []



func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true

    cell.textLabel?.text = "row=\(indexPath.row)section=\(indexPath.section) \(result[indexPath.section].name) \(result[indexPath.section].dateRanges[indexPath.row]) \(result[indexPath.section].hours[indexPath.row])"

    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(8.0)


    if let selectedPaths = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows {
        let selected = selectedPaths.filter(){ $0 == indexPath }
        if selected.count > 0 {
            cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
        } else {
            cell.accessoryType = .None
        }
    }

    return cell
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let indexpath = NSIndexPath(forRow: indexPath.row, inSection: indexPath.section)

    if (selectedMarks2.contains(result[indexpath.row])){

        if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
            cell.accessoryType = .None
        }
        print("erase")
        selectedMarks2.removeObject(result[indexPath.row])

    } else {


        if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
            cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
        }
        print("add")
        selectedMarks2.append(result[indexpath.section]) //add the object to selectedMarks

    }
    tableView.reloadData()

}
```

The thing is that I'm having problems when trying to add the selected row in his section of the table. If I select one row of any section, the selectionMarks2 variable appends all the rows of the same section. I want only to append the concrete row of the concrete section that I've selected. Can somebody help?

Comment: I recommend an` NSIndexSet` to store your selections. You will need an array of NSIndexSets - each element of the array will hold an index set for one section.

Comment: You should probably write `selectedMarks2.append(result[indexpath.row])` instead of `selectedMarks2.append(result[indexpath.section])`. And what are the strange `let indexpath =` shenanigans for?

Comment: See my answer here for a solution using NSMutableIndexSets - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30585625/parse-and-swift-get-cells-in-uitableview-which-have-a-checkmark-cannot-invoke/30585696#30585696