# How do i deselect my selected checkmark in viewController

Tags: ios, swift2, viewcontroller, checkmark

import UIKit

class RightSideViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate {

```
var tableView: UITableView!
var textField: UITextField!
var menuItems:[String]=["A","B","C","All"];

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
```

// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

```
@available(iOS 2.0, *)
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return menuItems.count;
}

@available(iOS 2.0, *)
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{

    let leftCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("RightCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! RightSideTableViewCell
    leftCell.projectsName.text = self.menuItems[indexPath.row]


    return leftCell
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    let mySelectedCell:UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!


    // when find checkmark then unchecked

    if mySelectedCell.accessoryType == .Checkmark
    {
        mySelectedCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
    }
    else
    {
        mySelectedCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
        print(menuItems[indexPath.row])

    }

   // when click on "all" deselect all selected checks 
    if indexPath.row == menuItems.count-1
    {
       // i want to deselect my all selected checkmark here
    }




}
```

}

i'm unable to deselect clicked check here

Comment: You can't rely on the accessory in the cell as cell objects are reused. I suggest you use an NSMutableIndexSet to store selected indexes and then you will need to refer to this in cellForRowAtIndexPath in order to set/clear the check mark. Deselect all is then simply a matter of removing the indices from the set and reloading those rows

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the state of the selected cells in a NSMutableSet and then you need to refer to this set to remove check-marks from selected cells. (Just as Paul said rightfully). You can refer to the below answer.

[Parse and Swift. Get cells in UITableView which have a checkmark. "Cannot invoke argument.“](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30585625/parse-and-swift-get-cells-in-uitableview-which-have-a-checkmark-cannot-invoke)